# Show clicks count for bit.ly link

Tags: jquery, json, bit.ly

I've been searching for an hour and couldn't find how to do this simple thing.

I'm sorry if it's a dumb question, but I just want to get the number of clicks a particular bit.ly link has. I don't need to do it with a bunch of links, just one specific bit.ly link...

Is it possible to do this with jQuery and Json, or is there a simpler way?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure how you can do this, but I'm certain that bit.ly exposes an API to get the clicks of a link

http://code.google.com/p/bitly-api/wiki/ApiDocumentation#/v3/clicks

It uses JSONP. To use this, you can call http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/ and set the `datatype` as `jsonp`, and display it from the data returned

Answer (score 0):

You can get this information through bitly's REST api:
http://code.google.com/p/bitly-api/wiki/ApiDocumentation#/v3/clicks